# Combining two tables and replacing values with unique identifier

Tags: sql, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have two tables that both contain a unique identifier for the data sets. One table has all the data I need, including email address. The other table has about 3,000 rows that have a different email address for some records. How can I combine this two tables with SQL and simple replace the email address for those that have a record in the second table, but keep all the data from the first table except email address?

Comment: LEFT JOIN, COALESCE

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COALESCE(EMAIL2, EMAIL1)
FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2
on T1.ID = T2.ID
```

This will set the email address as the email from the second table if it exists, otherwise it will keep the email address from the first table.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have.

SELECT COALESCE(UABMCEMail.Email, UABEmail.EMAIL)
FROM UABEmail
LEFT JOIN UABMCEmail
ON UABEmail.LDAP_ID = UABMCEmail.LDAP_ID

UABMCEmail is the table with just about 3,000 emails, however, they all have emails in UABEmail already, they are not null.

I am getting "Errors: No column name was specified for column 1 of 'Qry'."

Comment: SELECT COALESCE(UABMCEMail.Email, UABEmail.EMAIL) as Email. You need to add an alias

Comment: That worked perfect, now how do I get the rest of the fields moved over from Table 1 (UABEmail) to be in the new table.

Comment: Well, you could SELECT INTO a new table. Or do you want to update one of the two original tables?

Comment: I am in Salesforce Marketing Cloud, so the SQL is using the two tables (data extensions) and making a new third one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to update the 1st table? If so:

```
update table1 inner join table2 
on table2.id = table1.id
set table1.email = table2.email
where table2.email is not null
```